# Word Problem about Measure of Central Tendency

Tags: statistics, word-problem

The mean of 2 numbers is 45. The range is 30. What are the 2 numbers?

I know that x+y/2 = 45, and for the range, I know that I should be subtracting the lowest value from the highest one. However, I am having a hard time in combining both of these concepts to contruct an equation that will yield the answer.

Any help will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "an equation". You have two unknowns, so you need two equations.

Let $y$ be the larger number. We have $\frac{x + y}{2} = 45$, as you wrote, and $y - x = 30$, which you didn't write but seemed to grasp.

You now have your two equations.

Comment: Thank you. I arrived at 60 & 30 for my unknowns.